# AWS "Malformed Lambda proxy response" despite correct callback

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I'm just starting with Serverless, and other funny things alike - therefore pardon me if I'd sound basic on some levels.

I started following the tutorial under this link: [part 1](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/09/15/serverless-jam---a-serverless-framework-tutorial/), [part 2](http://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/10/13/serverless-jam---a-serverless-framework-tutorial-part-2/).
After sucessufully installing and configuring things, after getting to the part when a curl request must be called to test `addRating` function, instead of the desired output i get iths error:

```
HTTP/2 502
content-type: application/json
content-length: 36
date: Thu, 21 Jun 2018 09:59:35 GMT
x-amzn-requestid: cd0xxx
x-amz-apigw-id: I0xxx
x-cache: Error from cloudfront
via: 1.1 c438xxx.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: MFxxx==
```

I have tried looking around the net for answers but found nothing in particular.
Some info suggests I need to setup my API Gateway, but on the other hand I see it working perfectly in the tutorial, without any api gateways configured.
What could be the issue here, and what is the best way to approach it?

## UPDATE:

After help from Michael I have managed to find the API gateway that was sent to AWS on the first project deploy. Turned out having a different location that the one in the API resulted in it not being visible in the list.

Running tests the real issue was named to be `Malformed Lambda proxy response`. Research suggests the issue is occurring due to to wrong response from functions. I have updated my response to look like so:

```
callback(null, {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ averageRating: average }),
      isBase64Encoded: false
    })
```

In order to match the [Amazon docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/malformed-502-api-gateway/) better. However - the issue still persists.

What's more, the test "hello" function works properly, despite having the callback look like this:

```
const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!',
      input: event,
    }),
  };

  callback(null, response);
```

**update:**
Setting the callback to `context.succeed(response);` results in the same issue

Comment: You can disregard `x-cache`, `via`, and `x-amz-cf-id`.  They are not going to help you troubleshoot or understand the error, because they appear here due to side-effects of the way API Gateway edge-optimized endpoints are provisioned inside the AWS infrastructure.  However, `x-amz-apigw-id` is the ID of an existing API you have indeed already deployed in API Gateway.  You might try to go find that.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I don't have any API Gateways setup in AWS atm. Should I set one up and somehow connect it to serverless?

Comment: You may not realize it, but you do have one. You deployed it while following the tutorial. The hostname in the URL you're accessing is -- I assume -- something like `example.execute-api.xx-yyyy-n.amazonaws.com`.  `execute-api` means an API Gateway endpoint, and `xx-yyyy-n` is the AWS region (I'm guessing us-east-1, which is Northern Virginia, but you might have changed this in config). That's where this error is coming from.  Find that in the AWS console.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot You were right! After changing to us-east and checking the API gateways I have found the one for the app

Comment: According to the Console the issue was `Malformed Lambda proxy response`. I will look it up on google to see how to solve it. 
@Michael-sqlbot you can put your comment as an answert. Perhaps it would help some other noobs :)

Comment: It sounds like you are on the right track... we should probably go ahead and troubleshoot this further, and make the answer more useful to others, in the future.  A malformed Lambda proxy response means your Lambda function isn't forming its response object correctly, **or** it's throwing an exception (which is of course also "malformed" in the sense that it doesn't match what API Gateway expects... and API Gateway does not try to show that to the original caller, since that could contain sensitive info).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have updated the question to better match new data. Please check then